# Run a script after page loaded without using onload funcion

Tags: javascript, jquery

we use `<body onload="f1()">` for doing something onload

Is there anyway i can run a script `f1 function` after a page is loaded fully ??

Please answer with an example (jsfiddle preferred)

Comment: *"Fully loaded"* means all images are loaded?

Comment: _jsfiddle preferred_.....I think this is needed from your side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$(window).load(function() {` event executes a bit later when the complete page is fully loaded, including all frames, objects and images

Using jQuery

```
<script>
$(window).load(function() {
    alert( "window loaded" );
    f1(); // Your function call
});
</script>
```

Using Pure JS

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    alert( "window loaded" );
    f1(); // Your function call
};
</script>
```

Comment: @LynAs, Just to confirm. As you have tagged jQuery. Is jquery loaded? I have updated answer to do using pure JS

Answer (score 1):

```
 <script>
    f1();
 </script>
```

add this script before closing body tag i.e

```
</body>
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think this will run after all the DOM is loaded, but not necessarily after all the elements (stylesheets, scripts, objects, and especially images) are loaded, which is what I understand "fully loaded" means...

Answer (score 0):

You can put your function inside `$(window).load(function() { ... });`:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    f1();
});
```

Code included inside `$( window ).load(function() { ... })` will run once the entire page (images or iframes), not just the DOM, is ready.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following method so that your function will be loaded nce a web page has completely loaded all content (including images, script files, CSS files, etc.).

```
<body onload="f1()">
```